# ASP.NET Core server rejects websocket connection outside the project

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-core, windows-10

When I am trying to connect to ASP.NET Core websocket server from a html page within the wwwroot, the server reacts as expected, a websocket is connected, messages are sent/received, and etc.

But when I'm moving the html page outside the root folder it simply doesn't want to connect. I am on Windows 10 machine and I know that here, the firewall restricts loopbacks for socket connections (on Windows apps), is this the same case here or is it a IIS or asp.net core configuration ?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files

Comment: static files should be inside wwwroot by default or you should do special configuration.

Comment: Static page is working just fine and the websocket connection is working too. The problem is when I'm trying to connect to the websocket from external page outside the project.

Comment: It's kind of API but with socket connections

Comment: but maybe is it related?

Comment: After researching a bit I found that it is IIS express related, but still without any solution.